# Get class pointer from a vector via function argument

Tags: c++, pointers

I have a class

```
class MyClass {
   public:
     string name;
};
```

I have a class manager, with a vector of said classes.

```
class MyManager { 
 public:
   vector<MyClass> classes;
};
```

I want to pull out a class from the vector by looping and matching with the name

```
int MyManager::FindMyClass(string name, MyClass *clazz){
    vector<MyClass>::iterator it;
    for(it = classes.begin(); it != classes.end(); ++it){
        if(it->name == name){
            // if i cout here, i see the cout, so i did find it..
            *clazz = *it;
            return 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    MyClass *myClass;
    int result = myManager.FindMyClass("bob", *myClass);
}
```

I know for a fact that the object is matched properly (see the comment). I've tried every combination of pointers, double pointers, references, and get every error from unknown conversions to invalid pointers. I am just not sure what I have to do to get a reference to the class stored in the vector.

Comment: `myManager.FindMyClass("bob", *myClass);` is a type error. `*myClass` is a `MyClass`, not a `MyClass *`. If it weren't a type error, it would have undefined behavior: You're trying to read from an uninitialized variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the argument type to `MyClass*&` so you can return a pointer to the object found in the `vector`.

```
int MyManager::FindMyClass(string name, MyClass* &foundPointer)
```

```
MyClass *myClass;
int result = myManager.FindMyClass("bob", myClass);
```

Once you find the match, you can get a pointer to the object using

```
foundPointer = &(*it);
```

I would also recommend changing the return type to `bool`.

Here's an updated version of the function:

```
bool MyManager::FindMyClass(string name, MyClass* &foundPointer)
{
   vector<MyClass>::iterator it = classes.begin();
   for(; it != classes.end(); ++it)
   {
      if(it->name == name)
      {
         foundPointer = &(*it);
         return true;
      }
   }
   return false;
}
```

---

Suggested second improvement:

Change the return type to `MyClass*`. Return a pointer to the found object or `nullptr` if none is found.

```
MyClass* MyManager::FindMyClass(string name)
{
   ...
}
```

---

Suggested third improvement:

Use the standard library function [`std::find_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) and a lambda expression to simplify your function.

```
auto it = std::find_if(classes.begin(),
                       classes.end(),
                       [&](const MyClass &c) { return (c.name == name); });
```

---

The updated function:

```
MyClass* MyManager::FindMyClass(string name)
{
   auto it = std::find_if(classes.begin(),
                          classes.end(),
                          [&](const MyClass &c) { return (c.name == name); });
   if ( it != classes.end() )
   {
      return &(*it);
   }
   return nullptr;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This works perfectly. Would you be able to explain it a bit more.. I am struggling very hard with pointers and just don't understand what is going on with `MyClass*&`  as well as `foundPointer = &(*it)`

Comment: @JDoe., those are fundamental aspects of the language. You will be better off picking a text book and reading through it to understand the basics. Here's a [starting point](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: Instead of using an output parameter, I would `return &(*it);` the matching object, and `return nullptr;` if no match is found: `MyClass *myClass = myManager.FindMyClass("bob");` And consider using `std::find_if()` instead of a manual loop: `auto it = std::find_if(classes.begin(), classes.end(), [&](const MyClass &c) { return (c.name == name); });`

Comment: Thanks but I should have specified im stuck pre-c++ 11, i think c++ 98